# Is it easy to protect against SSI injection?

Tags: injection, validation

SSI injection is, to the best of my understanding, the process of injecting commands into user input fields, e.g.

`&lt;!--#exec cmd="ls" --&gt;`

to get the files in the current directory. However, while seemingly powerful, it also seems incredibly easy to prevent by simply validating input fields. For example, one could just check to see if the first three characters in any input field is `&lt;!-` and prevent such inputs.

Is there something I'm missing here? When is it not easy to prevent SSI injection? I'm new to network security so please forgive any misunderstandings there may be in the above paragraph.

Comment: You would be surprised how seldom developers think about sanitizing / validating inputs.

Comment: *Input* validation is almost never the answer to injection problems. You generally need to apply proper *output* encoding.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm not big on httpd stuff, but wouldn't `IncludesNOEXEC` pretty much be the guaranteed solution?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Isn't SSI handled at the web server level rather than in code?

Comment: @WorseDoughnut - I think an attacker could still try to grab sensitive information and display it using SSI injection.  Example: `<!--#include virtual="/etc/passwd" -->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a terribly difficult attack to prevent.  I would say prevention has more to do with the developer being security aware than it does with the complexity of preventing it.  This is actually true of many security vulnerabilities.

To answer your question - no, I don't think you are missing anything.  It's just a matter of making sure developers are thinking about security when they implement functionality that uses SSI.